# Splitting FASTA sequence using Python

Tags: python, biopython

The following error message appears when I try to run the following script: 
Background: I am trying to split up a large FASTA file (~45Mb) into smaller files based on gene id. I would like to chop it everytime the ">" appears. The following .py script allows me to do so. However, everynow and then I get the following error. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
Script:
 import os 
    os.chdir("/vmb/Flavia_All/Python_Commands")
    outfile = os.chdir("/vmb/Flavia_All/Python_Commands")

import sys
infile = open(sys.argv[1])
outfile = []

for line in infile:
    if line.startswith(">"):
        if (outfile != []): outfile.close()
        genename = line.strip().split('|')[1]
        filename = genename+".fasta"
        outfile = open(filename,'w')
        outfile.write(line)
    else:
        outfile.write(line)
outfile.close()
```

Error Message when script is run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "splitting_fasta.py", line 14, in <module>
    outfile = open(filename,'w')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'AY378100.1_cds_AAR07818.1_173 [gene=pbrB/pbrC] [protein=PbrB/PbrC] [protein_id=AAR07818.1] [location=complement(152303..153451)].fasta'
```

*NOTE: AY378100.1_cds_AAR07818.1 is one of many genes in this FASTA sequence. This is not the only gene i have had the same message appear with. I would like to stop deleting each gene that comes up with this message.

Comment: I can suggest a simple Unix command-line solution (in case of added tags `linux`, `splitting`)

Comment: Can we see a small excerpt of the FASTA file?

Comment: Yes. Here is a small sample: >lcl|AY378100.1_cds_AAR07812.1_167 [gene=LV174] [protein=conserved hypothetical protein] [protein_id=AAR07812.1] [location=complement(147139..147465)]
TTGCTATACGTTCGTGTTGTGTTATTCTTGTATACCAATTGCTATACAGGAGAGGTGTGTATGAAATCAG
ATGTTCAACTCAACCTAAGAGCTAAAGAGTCTCAGAGAGTACTCATCGATGCCGCTGCAGAGATCCTTCA
TAAATCGCGAACCGACTTTATCCTGGAGATGGCCTGCAAGGCTGCGGAGAATGTGATCCTTGATCGCCGT
GTTTTCAATTTTAACGACGAACAGTATGCAGAGTTCATCGATATGCTCGATGCACCAGTCGAGGATGATT
CCGCCATTAATAAACTACTGGCAAGGAAACCTCAGTGGGACGTATAA
>lcl|AY378100.1_cds_AAR07814.1_169 [gene=LV172] ....

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some of the fasta "names" (the first description line with the `>`) contains too much. In particular contains some characters not allowed in file names.

If names like the GenBank ID - `AY378100` are sufficiently unambiguous then:

```
genename = line.strip().split('|')[1].split('.')[0]
```

may be OK. If you have many fasta sequences with the same ID you probably will be OK with:

```
genename = line.strip().split('|')[1].split('[')[0].strip()
```